# No image on third monitor on dual gpu Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, xorg, gpu

I have a following system:

- Ubuntu 18.04;
- Kernel 5.4.0-131-generic;
- 2x Nvidia GT1030 with 2 interfaces each: DisplayPort and HDMI;
- Monitors connected to DP and HDMI on the first card and to HDMI on the second;
- Nvidia 515 drivers installed.

I don't have any picture from 2nd GPU. Both GPUs are fine, I've tested it by leaving only one connected and there were no problems. But when I connect both GPUs, I only get image from first one. Monitors and PCIs out of question also, I've tried all variations of setup.

I've tried:

- purging and reinstalling nvidia drivers;
- deleting x's config and reconfiguring;
- enabling BaseMosaic and Xinerama;
- setting metamodes;
- booting with pci=realloc option;
- a lot of googling.

I'm out of ideas. I'd like some ideas on what can be a problem there.
Here's some outputs and logs:

- [xrandr](https://github.com/paVVin/fileDrop/blob/02cf5d4c5109fd29ba6632548f2a3cad46d9323d/xrandr.txt) (it doesnt show second HDMI no matter what);
- [xrandr --listproviders](https://github.com/paVVin/fileDrop/blob/02cf5d4c5109fd29ba6632548f2a3cad46d9323d/xrandr-providers.txt) (shows only one provider);
- [lspci](https://github.com/paVVin/fileDrop/blob/02cf5d4c5109fd29ba6632548f2a3cad46d9323d/lspci.txt) (both cards are connected and detected properly);
- [lshw -C video](https://github.com/paVVin/fileDrop/blob/02cf5d4c5109fd29ba6632548f2a3cad46d9323d/lshw.txt) (both cards are there, but for some reason they have same physical ID, I tried to connect different GPU in the second slot and it still had same ID as first one);
- [nvidia-bug-report](https://github.com/paVVin/fileDrop/blob/02cf5d4c5109fd29ba6632548f2a3cad46d9323d/nvidia-bug-report.log.gz)
- [here](https://github.com/paVVin/fileDrop) you can find some xorg configs that I've tried.

Comment: I wish I had a second video card in my system, let alone another PCIe slot to try this out, but as far as I know you need to SLI the two cards together so that they act as one.  See https://enterinit.com/how-to-enable-nvidia-sli-in-ubuntu/ as it tells you how to do it via command line.